# Convert rgb images to grayscale images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I have a numpy array of rgb images as shown below

```
print(train_frames.shape) #(100, 40, 120, 140, 3)
```

which means 100 rows each of 40 frames contains an image of 120x140.

I need to convert that into gray scale images i.e,

```
print(train_frames.shape) #(100, 40, 120, 140, 1)
```

How to convert that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in batch, one way is to use numpy.mean

```
numpy.mean(train_frames, axis=-1)
```

axis=-1 means the 3 rgb channels.

If you want to get a better conversion, I guess you will need to convert image by image with opencv `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: When I am using that cv2.cvtColor thing, I am getting array shape of only (100, 40, 120, 160) instead of (100, 40, 120, 160, 1)

Comment: To use cvtColor you must iterate on the (100, 40) matrix with 120x160x3 images. Each image should be converted to a 120x160x1. Got it?